# how to change a.m. and p.m. to uppercase in a timepicker?

Tags: android, timepicker

Whenever i change the language of the system to canadian english the a.m. and p.m. symbols go into lowercase otherwise it is always in uppercase

Actual:

[image: the a.m. and p.m. are in lower case. right now the system language is canadian english]

Expected:

[image: the a.m. and p.m. are in uppercase. right now the system language is canadian french]

The code for simpleDateFormat():

```
 public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
    {
        if (pattern == null || locale == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        initializeCalendar(locale);
        this.pattern = pattern;
        this.formatData = DateFormatSymbols.getInstanceRef(locale);
        this.locale = locale;
        initialize(locale);
    }
```

Comment: Share your code of SimpleDateFormat

Comment: updated as requested @Shane

Comment: What parameter you passing in SimpleDateFormat's Locale?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT_24HRS, Locale.ENGLISH)

Comment: Change your Locale to Locale.US

Comment: no difference can be seen

Comment: Funny, on my Java 9 `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-CA")` produces uppercase `PM`. Maybe Android is different?